# How can I deploy a VB.Net 1.1 app with no manufacturer set

Tags: vb.net, deployment, .net-1.1

I need to deploy this app and currently the installer the path goes something like "C:\Program Files\Manufacturer\App".  I just want it to be "C:\Program Files\App" by default.

I know I can change this manufacturer from the properties for the project, but I want it to go away altogether.  The setup project won't build with it gone.  Any way to get around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming a VS Deployment, in your setup project:

1. Go to the "File System" tab
2. Select the `Application Folder`
3. In the properties pane, change `[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]` to `[ProgramFilesFolder]\[ProductName]`

Answer (score 0):

Just set it to an empty string.

Comment: by empty string, do you mean just nothing?  It won't compile if I put nothing in there.  I did just find if I put a space in there it works fine, which is stupid.